# GSON-JSON Deserialize Object in Class

Tags: java, json, gson

I've a little problem with GSON-JSON.

Let see the following code:

```
    public static class ProtoQuery {
    public String action;
    public String token;
    public Object params;

    public ProtoQuery(String action, String token, Object params) {
        this.action = action;
        this.token = token;
        this.params = params;
    }
}


// Authentication Phase
public static class ProtoAuth {
    public String username;
    public String password;

    public ProtoAuth(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}


    // Serialize Object
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ProtoQuery tmp = new ProtoQuery("ProtoAuth", "", new JirckeProtocol.ProtoAuth("ABC", "myPASS"));
    String json = gson.toJson(tmp);

    // Deserialize Object
    ProtoQuery deserializedOBJ = gson.fromJson(json, ProtoQuery.class);
```

Here the problem:
deserializedOBJ.object return a LinkedHashMap.
I want to convert back into ProtoAuth object..How I can know that is a ProtoAuth? Using the "action" params in ProtoQuery.

I need something like
deserializedOBJ.params = gson.fromJSON(json.object, ProtoAuth.class)

What's the best way to do this?
There is an alternative to do this, without write my own serializer/deserialer?

Actually I use that code:

```
deserializedOBJ.params = gson.fromJson(element, Class.forName("MyProtocol$ProtoAuth"));
```

Comment: I suppose you can't declare params as a "ProtoAuth"?

Comment: No, because params can be ProtoAuth, ProtoReq, ProtoStatus, ProtoEcc... I wrap my query in classes, I think is usefull for better documentation (an external developer can read the Protocol.java and the inner class and know what request do and the params of each query)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would type ProtoQuery as following:

```
public static class ProtoQuery<T> {
    public String action;
    public String token;
    public T params;

    public ProtoQuery(String action, String token, T params) {
        this.action = action;
        this.token = token;
        this.params = params;
    }
}


// Authentication Phase
public static class ProtoAuth {
    public String username;
    public String password;

    public ProtoAuth(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

and to deserialize with a param of type ProtoAuth, you can call as followed:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<ProtoQuery<ProtoAuth>>() {}.getType();
ProtoQuery<ProtoAuth> deserializedOBJ = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Comment: Mmm...In this case you know at compile time the TYPE, in my case I don't know, so I must use that: Type type = new TypeToken<ProtoQuery<Class.forName("MyProtocol$ProtoAuth"))>>() {}.getType();  - Anyway I think that solution is easy and works well.. Another little question, if ProtoAuth include also another type (Strings user/pass substitued with an object like UserInfo) can I deserialize without problem?

Comment: @Kaiser69 You can do pretty much everything you want with GSon to deserialize JSon strings. The only constraints is during deserialization: GSon has to know the types that will be deserialized. So if your field is typed with UserInfo, it will have no issues. If it is typed with a super-class or a super-interface, then you will has some problems. Those problems can be solved by using a TypeAdapter.

Comment: I don't understand a little thing in that example...I don't know the type of the de-serialized object. In my question, I put a sample code that firstly decode the base class (ProtoQuery), then de-serialize the next element (Object -> ProtoAuth)

Comment: @Kaiser69 At some point, you will have to know what "Type" you expect. Anyway, if you want to delegate this to the latest moment, you could probably change the type of "params" to JsonElement and then later on do `new Gson().fromGson(params, ProtoAuth.class);`

Comment: Of course in my "action" field I know the type, but initially I think that gson.fromJson() overwrite my actual object..So I must deserialized two times..

Comment: @Kaiser69 Like I said, you can always change the type of `params` to `JsonElement` and deserialize later the `params` value using Gson again.

Comment: Fantastic :) This worked good for me when trying to serialize and cast against Object.